# How to call out path of local pictures library in ASP.NET web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, visual-studio, webforms

So i have a ASP.NET web app in c#. I've create a method to download files and it works fine. Currently, it's donwloading files in D drive as i pointed out that path. However, i want the files to be downloaded in Local Pictures Library.
Below are my codes:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Download")
  {
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/octect-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + e.CommandArgument);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    //How to add path for pictures library in local machine?
    webClient.DownloadFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + e.CommandArgument, @"d:\myfile.jpg");
    Response.End();
  }
}
```

Comment: The pictures library is an enumeration of Windows folders. By default it's these two: c:\Users\<windows account name>\My Pictures and c:\Users\Public\Public Pictures

Comment: Do you want to change the path that the file is downloaded to on the computer of the user or on the server?

Comment: @Markus On the server

Comment: @Sangman Hi it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the path of the My Pictures library on the server, you can use the [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, e.g.:

```
var path = Path.Combine( 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), 
    "myfile.jpg");
webClient.DownloadFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + e.CommandArgument, path);
```

This will use the MyPictures folder of the account that the application pool is using.

Comment: is it GetSpecialFolderPath or GetFolderPath if i put in GetSpecialFolderPath, i get errors- Environment doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you ! Your codes work. Just that it's GetFolderPath instead of GetSpecialFolderPath

Comment: @alisafathima good to hear that it worked. Sorry - GetSpecialFolderPath was wrong. Only the enumeration is called `SpecialFolder`.